# How changing number of workers will effect the Glue job

Tags: optimization, timeout, aws-glue, worker

I have 2200000 records to process in Glue job which is leading to timeout as by default it is set to 2 days and number of workers are 10 . Increasing the number of workers will help in running the glue job faster ??

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the numbers of worker will help to run the job faster, if your job has transformations that can run in parallel since you are allocating more executor nodes.

2200000 records isn't that much though, and you should check if somethings wrong with the code if it takes > 2 days.

Comment: i am reading too many small files in for loop one by one in dataframe and i am not able to caolesce it or merge it       ====================                                                                                           for path,time in zip((file_list),(file_time)):
                input_file_path = "s3://" +  config_object['inp_bucket'] + "/" + path
                inp_df = sqlContext.read.options(header='True').parquet(input_file_path)